# wallet software that doesn't require downloading the entire blockchain

Tags: blockchain, wallet

I find 99.999% of the blockchain irrelevant and a wasteful use of storage space in my personal computers. I just need it to sync my wallets.

on OSX what are bitcoin softwares that do not require downloading the entire blockchain? How can I find the wallet of my currently installed software (Bitcoin-Qt) and move it

Answer (score 2):

Electrum wallet. Works like a charm on my mac.

Comment: thanks I had downloaded that but wasn't sure what I was looking at, how do I move an existing wallet to it?

Comment: An electrum wallet is a series of addresses based on a seed: http://electrum.org/seed.html  Use your bitcoin-qt client to pay yourself at one of the addresses that you get from Electrum.

Answer (score 2):

MultiBit is available for OSX. 
https://multibit.org

This only uses the block headers (included in the download - about 20 MB). 
There is a version in test that replaces this with a checkpoints file which is only 12 kilobytes.